# Is there a way to create a modification of Breed-On that includes specific characteristics?

Tags: netlogo

I want my forager turtles to follow a path laid down by leader turtles, and this path consists of a turtle breed called trail-markers. The forager turtles also lay down trail-markers (to reinforce the trail), so I would like them to check for leader trail-markers on some patch/patches. I know Netlogo includes breeds-on to check for the presence of members of a breed, but I need the foragers to check for blue leader trail-markers. Is there a way to do this?

Here is what I had in mind:

```
if count (trail-markers with [color = blue]) on patch-ahead 1 > 0 [fd 1]
```

But I got, error:nothing named on has been defined, which makes sense, since the Netlogo primitive is breeds-on, so I modified it to:

```
  if any? (trail-markers with [color = blue])-on patch-ahead 1 [fd 1]
```

However, I simply received: *error:nothing named -on has been defined* instead.

Comment: that code looks fine, what error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

See the code below.  I think you just want [to use `trail-markers-on`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-on), but [you can simplify by using `any?`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any) a bit.  And you might want to have the custom reporter so you can just check for `blue-markers-on` if you find that simpler.

```
breed [ trail-markers trail-marker ]

to example
  ; I think this is what you want
  if count ((trail-markers-on patch-ahead 1) with [color = blue]) > 0 [ forward 1 ]

  ; this is slightly simpler, using `any?` instead of `count ... > 0`
  if any? (trail-markers-on patch-ahead 1) with [color = blue] [ forward 1 ]

  ; you could also write a custom reporter if you'll need to get this info a lot
  if any? blue-markers-on patch-ahead 1 [ forward 1 ]
end

to-report blue-markers-on [p]
  report (trail-markers-on p) with [ color = blue ]
end
```